# Validation Error in ODOO

Tags: odoo-10, validationerror

How to stop raising validation error in ODOO 10
For example in project.py file I want to stop raising this validation error :

```
@api.constrains('date_start', 'date_end')
def _check_dates(self):
    if any(self.filtered(lambda task: task.date_start and task.date_end and task.date_start > task.date_end)):
        raise ValidationError(_('Error ! Task starting date must be lower than its ending date.'))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can disable that warning by overriding the function. Try below code,

```py
@api.constrains('date_start', 'date_end')
def _check_dates(self):
    if any(self.filtered(lambda task: task.date_start and task.date_end and task.date_start > task.date_end)):
       pass;
       #raise ValidationError(_('Error ! Task starting date must be lower than its ending date.'))
```

Hope it will help you.